# not able to control atomic behavior of AtomicInteger while subtracting value

Tags: java, multithreading, atomicinteger

This is the first time that I was using `java.util.concurrent.atomic` package for synchronization purpose in `multithreading`. I was trying to handle the classic example of `AccountDanger` class given in Kathy Sierra book for OCP through `java.util.concurrent.atomic`. But I was unable to protect the `balance` variable i.e `AtomicInteger` from being getting over withdrawn. Below is my code:

**Account class**

```
package p1;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Account {
  private AtomicInteger balance = new AtomicInteger(100);

  public int getBalance() {
    return balance.get();
  }

  public void withdraw(int amount) {
    balance.addAndGet(-amount);
    System.out.println("~~~~~~ " + balance);
  }
}
```

**AccountDanger class**

```
package p1;

public class AccountDanger implements Runnable {
  private Account account = new Account();
  private int amt = 10;

  public void run() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      if (account.getBalance() >= amt) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is going to withdraw..");
        try {
          Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        account.withdraw(amt);
      } else {
        System.out.println("not enough balance");
      }
      if (account.getBalance() < 0) {
        System.out.println("account is over withdrawn!!!");
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    AccountDanger ad = new AccountDanger();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(ad, "Mark");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(ad, "Phew");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    System.out.println("final balance left is : " + ad.account.getBalance());
  }
}
```

I know, I am definitely wrong somewhere. can any one rectify my solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using `AtomicInteger` (or, rather, `Account`) atomically.

```
if(account.getBalance()>=amt){
   // Other stuff
   account.withdraw(amt);
```

Other threads can change the balance inside that "other stuff".

In `Account`, you need a method like this, using [`AtomicInteger.compareAndSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#compareAndSet-int-int-):

```
boolean withdrawIfBalanceEquals(int balance, int amt) {
  return this.balance.compareAndSet(balance, balance - amt);
}
```

This *only* sets the `AtomicInteger` to `balance-amt` if its value is still equal to `balance`, and then returns `true`. If it has been changed since you read its value, `compareAndSet` will return `false`.

Then, in `AccountDanger`, you would use it like:

```
int balance = account.getBalance();
if (balance >= amt) {
  // Other stuff.
  account.withdrawIfBalanceEquals(balance, amt);
}
```

I leave it up to you to decide how best to handle the case of `withdrawIfBalanceEquals` returning `false`; one way is:

```
while (true) {
  int balance = account.getBalance();
  if (balance >= amt) {
    // Other stuff.
    if (account.withdrawIfBalanceEquals(balance, amt)) {
      // If true, we don't have to keep looping: we withdrew the
      // balance.
      break;
    }

    // If false, keep going: you'll read the balance again,
    // check if it's still greater than balance etc.

  } else {
    System.out.println("Not enough balance");
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that between the point in time where you check the balance (`if(account.getBalance()>=amt) {`) and the point in time where you actually withdraw (`account.withdraw(amt);`), the balance might have changed, e.g. lowered to an amount `<= amt`.

Let's look at a concrete scenario for clarity. If you have an account with a balance of `500` and you start two threads to withdraw `300` each, every transaction by itself is legal, since it does not overdraw, thus both checks of the `if`-statement will yield `true`. But the transactions do not know of each other. The first transaction lowers the balance by `300` to a value of `200`. The second transaction then lowers the balance to `-100`.

To fix this problem, you need to introduce some synchronization. One possibility would be to check the balance before withdrawal:

```
public void withdraw (int amount) {
    if (balance.get() > amount) {
        balance.addAndGet(-amount);
        System.out.println("~~~~~~ "+balance);
    } else {
        throw new InsufficientBalanceException();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I introdcued an `Exception` to signal that the transaction could not be executed. You are free to introduce your own code for this case. This shortens the time between the check and the actual change, but does not fix the problem entirely. For this, you have to ensure that while one thread checks and possibly modifies the balance, no other thread can. One way to enforce this is the [`synchronized` keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html):

```
public synchronized void withdraw(int amount) {
    if (balance.get() > amount) {
        balance.addAndGet(-amount);
        System.out.println("~~~~~~ "+balance);
    } else {
        throw new InsufficientBalanceException();
    }
}
```

Now, only one thread can call `withdraw(...)` on one instance at a time.

As @AndyTurner pointed out, if you already have a thread-safe data structure, like an `AtomicInteger` and have to `synchronize` around it, there might be something fishy. Each single operation on an `AtomicInteger` are atomic, but not multiple operations in sequence, which is why we had to introduce some synchronization. In this particular case, you can get rid of the `AtomicInteger` and replace it with a `volatile int`.

Comment: You should be suspicious about having to synchronize around an `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: The problem with `synchronized` is, it doesn’t protect your code unless *all* code modifying the value of `balance` uses `synchronized`.